# UDP broadcast not working for one PC in the LAN

Tags: windows, networking, lan, udp

I have a program that broadcasts a simple UDP message periodically to manifest presence in the LAN. I have a laptop and a desktop PC both connected to the home router through Wifi. Both computers run Windows.

I have noticed that the desktop PC detects the presence of the laptop. But the laptop doesn't detect the presence of the desktop. Even though they are running the exact same code.

Using Wireshark I found out that the messages desktop->laptop don't show up - no matter if I run Wireshark in either computer. However, messages laptop->desktop do show up in Wireshark - no matter if I run Wireshark in either computer.

I have also tried using my Android phone as a router and I get the exact same result.

I was wondering if there is any Windows setting that could be blocking the messages sent from desktop to laptop.

EDIT:

I have used "Packet Sender" to discard any possible problems with my app.

When I broadcast a packet from my **desktop PC**, it doesn't show up in Wireshark in any of the two computers. If the message is unicast, the message shows up in the Wireshark of both computers.

Using Packet Sender in the **laptop**, the broadcasted packet is registered in Wireshark in both computers.

It's weird that Wireshark doesn't register the outgoing broadcasted message in the desktop computer, isn't it? That makes me think the problem is not in the router, but in the computer itself.

EDIT2:

So I found something interesting. If I change the broadcast address from `255.255.255.255` to `192.168.0.255` it works! Why could that be?

Comment: `I was wondering if there is any Windows setting that could be blocking the messages sent from desktop to laptop.`, yes and it's called a firewall.

Comment: what application are you using to send/consume these broadcasts? does your wifi have an AP Isolation feature enabled?

Comment: If you run Wireshark on the sender and it doesn't see the sender sending the packet, then the sender is not sending the packet. What APIs is your code using the send these broadcasts? Does the API return an error when trying to send a packet on the machine that's not sending them? How does your code handle that error?

Comment: @Bib Thanks for the suggestion, I disabled the firewall in both computers. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: @FrankThomas It's my own application. I don't know about AP isolation; I have tried accessing the routers admin panel but haven't been able to. I'll try with another router later

Comment: @Spiff I'm using ENet's raw UDP sockets. I have an assert that checks the error but doesn't seem to trigger: `const int sentBytes = enet_socket_send(net.lanDiscoverySocket_manifest, &address, &buffer, 1); assert(sentBytes > 0);`

Comment: Okay, so I tried with a spare router I had around. I couldn't find "AP isolation" option but there is "Enable Client Isolation" which was disabled. Anyways, with this router it seems to get worse because none of the hosts can see each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found my problem.

I noticed that if I did the broadcast to `192.168.0.255` instead of `255.255.255.255` it worked.

Then upon further investigation I noticed that the `ipconfig` command returned a bunch of adapters in my desktop PC.

[image]

Looks like VirtualBox installation has added a bunch of virtual adapters to my system.

Using Wireshark, I confirmed that the messages where going though the wrong adapter. So the messages weren't going into my LAN.

In my laptop, I don't have any virtual adapters, that's why it was working with 255.255.255.255.

In order to fix the problem within my program, and make it resilient to different LAN configurations, I didn't hardcode 192.168.0.255 as the broadcast address. What I do instead it to loop though all the adapters and broadcast to each on of them. You need to compute the broadcast address as `ip_address | ~subnet_mask`.

Comment: ok. the fact that you are using a VM is critical to this equation. unless you were using a bridged network adapter, or taking special measures to accommodate a NAT network, it is expected that you will have difficulty reaching your LAN from the VM. 255.255.255.255 indicates a broadcast on all networks, so it makes sense that using it as a target would route the datagram out all interfaces, but that is probably not a good way to handle datagram scope if you ever intend to distribute the program for others to use. it would be better to let the user configure the binding interfaces.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm not using a VM

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/219764/255-255-255-255-vs-192-168-1-255

A special definition exists for the IP address 255.255.255.255. It is the broadcast address of the zero network or 0.0.0.0, which in Internet Protocol standards stands for this network, i.e. the local network. Transmission to this address is limited by definition, in that it is never forwarded by the routers connecting the local network to other networks.